# Automatically move div with javascript on delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I have the below piece of code that moves a  onto the screen when ?added is in the URL which works great. I now need to add a piece of code to it that then moves the  back over after 5 seconds. I have noticed there's a delay function but I'm not sure how to add it into the code. Can anyone help? Many thanks!

```
$(document).ready(
function () {
    if (document.URL.indexOf("?added") >= 0) {
        $('#popout-left-menu-container')
            .animate({
                'right': '2px'
            }, 300);
    };
});
```

Comment: possibly you should refer this http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the setTimeout function to delay something in javascript. Maybe like this:

```
$('#popout-left-menu-container').animate({'right':'2px'},300);

setTimeout(function(){
    //This is animation that runs after 5 seconds. You can use it to move the block back.
    //You have to set your parameters yourself here
    $('#popout-left-menu-container').animate({'right':'0px'},300);
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(
function () {
    if (document.URL.indexOf("?added") >= 0) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('#popout-left-menu-container')
                .animate({
                    right:'2px'
                },300);
        },5000);
    };

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do it with [`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/).

```
$("query").animate(firstAnimation, firstDuration).delay(milliseconds).animate(secondAnimation, secondDuration);
```